# My difficuly is I am unable to go further in the stalk from stslk

Tags: android

I am unable to move from C:\USERS\SYSTEM3> to C:\USERS\SYSTEM3|android-sdks>
 I checked out with cd from here by dir command and found the directory exists.
cd desktop is working, but cd documents is not working 
cd android-sdks is also not working.
cd Music is working
cd .. is working. how could I navigate to
C:\USERS\SYSTEM3\ANDROID-SDKS\PLATFORM-TOOLS from C:\USERS\SYSTEM3>

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to open a command prompt at a specific folder would be navigating to the folder in Windows explorer, then at an empty place hold Ctrl+Shift and right click. From the context menu you can open a command prompt.
Saves you the hassle of navigating with cd.